# Prevent scrollAssist & autoFocus on inputs that don't need keyboard to show

Tags: ionic2, ionic2-datetime

I built an Angular Reactive Form using Ionic 2.

When I was touching an input at the bottom of the page the page would scroll so the input get above the keyboard. Expected behavior, so ok. But the header was push too and that was wrong.

So I looked on the internet and find a workaround which was to write the following in the import statement of app.module.ts

```
// app.module    
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
   scrollAssist: true,
   autoFocusAssist: true
})
```

That indeed works well as the page still scrolls and the header is not push away.

But I still have one problème. When I touch an input which doesn't need the keyboard to be shown (eg. datepicker) the page scroll on the first touch and I have to touch again so the datepicker opens...

Any idea on how I could may be prevent the page to auto-scroll when touching an input that doesn't need the keyboard?

Comment: why do you want to use the datepicker for the `type=date` because when you add that attribute you don't need to bother about the scroll position and also that is a right way of UX like a native application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be possibly achieved by using two properties of `input` component. Firstly you can set the `readonly` property to true and then add the `click` Eventlistner to open the `DatePicker` and then use the `placeholder` property of input to show the value of `DatePicker`.

I hope this would help you find the solution. Let me know if this works.

**Good Luck & Cheers**

Ashish Sebastian

Comment: Actually the readonly property doesn't prevent the keyboard to show one first time... I the tried to use the disabled property, which works, but the style is different...